# using several independent variables in fbprophet model

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tend to use fbprophet like so to predict time series uni variate-ly:

```
import pandas as pd
from fbprophet import Prophet
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

stock = 'FB'

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Bla/' + stock + '.csv')
df['Date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date'])

df = df.rename(columns={'Date': 'ds',
                        'Close': 'y'})

my_model = Prophet(
    weekly_seasonality=True
    , interval_width=0.95
)
my_model.fit(df)

future_dates = my_model.make_future_dataframe(periods=5, freq='B')
future_dates.tail()

forecast = my_model.predict(future_dates)
forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].tail()

my_model.plot(forecast, uncertainty=True)
plt.show()
```

I think one can now also predict using multiple independent variables (using add_regressor?). Did someone do this? If so, could you please provide some code example? Let us assume the independent variable is called X1 in the above df. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not make a prediction with the additional regressor unless you add it during fitting. If you would like to add regressor to your model you should follow below steps (directly taken from the documentation):

```
def nfl_sunday(ds):
    date = pd.to_datetime(ds)
    if date.weekday() == 6 and (date.month > 8 or date.month < 2):
         return 1

    else:
         return 0

df['nfl_sunday'] = df['ds'].apply(nfl_sunday)

m = Prophet()
m.add_regressor('nfl_sunday')
m.fit(df)

future['nfl_sunday'] = future['ds'].apply(nfl_sunday)

forecast = m.predict(future)
fig = m.plot_components(forecast)
```